# Inserting page numbers in a Google Docs document Start at > 1

Tags: google-docs

I know Page numbers are available as a [part of Google Docs](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2011/08/this-week-in-docs-page-numbers-in.html).

By Selecting **Insert > Page number** from the file menu.

But How can I add footer page number start with a number greater than 1 on the first page, for example in a doc called chapter 2:

- The first page should start with number 44.
- All next pages should follow that, like 45, 46, 47 .. etc.

Is that something doable in Google Doc? even by a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Here, Finally, I found this:
"Workaround for Google Docs Page Numbering Problem to Start from a Specific Number"  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cGSqiKZ3wI

Simply just **create a word that contains paging start from a specific number and then upload it to Google drive**.
That's it.

You can use https://writer.zoho.com/writer